# Is there a short way to extract exactly one element from a `Vec`?

Tags: vector, rust

I have a reference to a `Vec` and I want to extract a reference to exactly one element from it, and panic if there are any more elements or zero. The equivalent if I had an array would be:

```rust
let [x] = list;
```

but `Vec`s are dynamically sized, so that won't work here. I can think of one way to do it with a reference to a `Vec`, and a couple more that require ownership, but I'm wondering if there's a shorter and simpler way.

#### *Un*owned Option 1: Use `assert!` and indexing

```rust
assert_eq!(list.len(), 1);
let x = &list[0];
```

---

#### Owned Option 1: Use `try_into()`

```rust
let [x]: [i32; 1] = list.try_into().unwrap();
```

#### Owned Option 2: Use `assert!` and `pop`

```rust
assert_eq!(list.len(), 1);
let x = list.pop();
```

---

So, is there a shorter and clearer way?

Comment: Another thing: these two options both require either ownership or mutable access, which I don't have in this case.

Comment: To make do without mutable access, you can use `list[0]` instead of `list.pop().unwrap()` in the second option, provided the item type of the vector is `Copy`.

Comment: In the tittle you ask for extract value but in your question you assume your list is exact one. the tittle and the body of your question doesn't match

Comment: @Stargateur What do you mean? I don't understand how they don't match.

Comment: *these two options both require either ownership or mutable access, which I don't have in this case* - Please [edit] the question to explain what you *do* have and why these options are insufficient. If you want to get an owned `T` out of a `Vec<T>` you will have to mutate or destroy the `Vec`... that's just what ownership is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [slice pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html) combined with [`let else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/let_else.html):

```
let v = vec![1u32];
let &[x] = v.as_slice() else {
    panic!("expected single element"); // or return, break, etc.
};
assert_eq!(x, 1);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=faba68aaec123d39818644413a02c880)

It's not necessarily shorter than your options, but it's clear and reasonably concise, doesn't require ownership or mutation, and can be nicely generalized to more than one element to extract.

If instead of panicking you want to check the element count and extract `x` if it's the only element, you can use `if let`:

```
if let &[x] = v.as_slice() {
   // ... use x ...
}
```

---

**EDIT**

This answer originally suggested the more verbose `match` syntax, which was mandatory before `let else` was introduced in Rust 1.65. It's still useful if you're contributing to a project that supports older compilers, or if you find `let else` unpalatable:

```
let x = match v.as_slice() {
    &[x] => x,
    _ => panic!("expected single element"),
};
```

Comment: in the same vein, `if let [x] = &list[..] { ...` is a possibility

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, that's works too, I've amended the answer to include it. A `match` would be my first case here because `if let` still requires an explicit `else` with panic (as per OP's requirements), and it forces the code that uses `x` to be indented in a block. The latter is not a big deal when you have only one `if let`, but if you have several, it tends to make the code ugly.

Comment: I don't get what this answer is for, OP ask for extract a value, your answer with match a slice that is exactly a value, unless I miss something, the question is unclear and so your answer is off topic at best

Comment: Note: if you can't move out of the slice, skip the `&` in the pattern.

Comment: @Stargateur The question was not just about extracting a value, but also about panicking if the vector is not single-element. (The OP additionally clarified that the code in question doesn't own the vector.) My answer shows how to do that in a reasonably short/clear code. Why would the answer be off-topic?

Comment: @Camelid Note that if you omit the `&`, you'll get a _reference_ to the value in the vector, rather than a copy of the value. If the value is not `Copy`, you probably need to do that, and clone the value.

Comment: Yes, in this case I can't move out of the vector and a reference is fine. Thanks for the great answer by the way!

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools`, works for both owned and non-owned versions:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

// Reference
let x = list.iter().exactly_one().expect("more or less than one");
// Owned
let x = list.into_iter().exactly_one().expect("more or less than one");
```